# How to Stretch Midi Notes and Position in Logic Pro X

Tags: midi

Reason 999 why FL studio is better than logic, but I want to use Alchemy so here we are.
In FL studio there is an easy option to stretch multiple midi notes and their placement so it is easier to change the duration of a melody or sequence of notes. Example if i had a melody that was 2 beats and I wanted it to change it so its 4 beats I can use command+a(on mac) and then there is a stretch icon to the right of the furthest note selected which allows me to do this.

However when I try this on Logic Pro the notes get stretched but they stay in the same place. I'll add some photos to show what i mean.

FL:

[image]

[image]

Logic:

[image]

[image]

Basically I want to know if there is a way to do this in Logic Pro X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. If you want to double the length and spacing of all notes in a region, then press the option key while dragging the bottom right-hand corner of the region in the tracks window:

This...

[image]

...becomes this...

[image]

If you just want to edit some notes within a region (which I think is what you are showing), use the **Half Speed** function found in **Functions->MIDI Transform**:

[image]

Assuming you have selected the notes you want to edit, press **Operate Only** in the dialog window that opens:

[image]

Just one thing to be aware of: this won't change the region length, so you may need to now lengthen the region to see the moved notes.

As with all the **MIDI Transform** functions in Logic, this gives you a great deal of flexibility. By changing the two number values in the **Half Speed** window, you could for example, triple the spacing of the notes but half their length etc. etc.